# perl - how to take part of a line

Tags: perl

I want to take a part of line using perl
example for 2 lines:

```
/Tests/CpuStrmRd_MemAccSmB_WrBgDis_RdBgDis_WrAlcDis__Ddr64_2to1_DlbEn_PrfEn_1_StrmRd/
/Tests/puStrmWr_MemAccSmB_WrBgDis_RdBgRnd_WrAlcEN__Ddr64_2to1_DlbEn_PrfEn_81_StrmWr/
```

and the part of the line (for each line) I want to take is:

```
CpuStrmRd_MemAccSmB_WrBgDis_RdBgDis_WrAlcDis
```

(which is between **/Tests/**  and **__Ddr** )

Thanks for any help

Comment: What have you tried? It seems like it'd be fairly straightforward to do this with a regular expression?

Comment: Be more specific and post the code that you have tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's between /Tests/ and __Ddr, it sounds like

```
my ($match) = ($line =~ m{/Tests/(.+?)__Ddr});
```

That will do literally what you are asking for; . matches any character.

Comment: what is the minning of ($line =~ **m** and the (.+?)

Comment: Well, as I said, the dot (.) matches any character; + means one or more, and ? tells it to stop the first time it matches, don't look for the biggest string that does it (this one is probably not necessary in this case). But you should definitely have a look at perldoc perlretut for that and other surprising functionalities :-)

Comment: If you have the strings in a file, you can do:<br/> `my @Parts = map m{/Tests/(.+?)__Ddr}g, <FILEHANDLE>; `